# Operator '==' cannot be applied to operands of type 'KeyValuePair' and 'string'?

Tags: c#, linq, dictionary

This question might appear to be a duplicate and/or too boring, but I want to do this using *this specific method*.

When a user enters a string into a textbox I want to get this string key. So to do this I've created a dictionary which has n (n <= 15000) unique values. I want to get the key from this dictionary by value. The method below works well:

```
Dictionary<int, string> artikullar = new Dictionary<int, string>();
int key = (from elem in artikullar where elem.Value == txt_artikul.Text select elem).First().Key;
```

Before that I tried to use the `First()` method to get the key:

```
int key = artikullar.AsParallel().First(new Func<KeyValuePair<int, string>, bool>(val => val == txt_artikul.Text)).Key;
```

But it throws this error:

> Operator '==' cannot be applied to operands of type 'KeyValuePair' and 'string'

I haven't used this method before.

Any helpful comment or answer would be appreciated.

Comment: Why are you holding a `Dictionary<int, string>`, shoulden't it be a `Dictionary<string, int>` if you are doing the lookup by the string? Also, if you have the same value for multiple keys your function may return a different `key` each time you run the function, is that acceptable?

Comment: @ScottChamberlain thanks to quick response. Well, the values should be stored as type of string and keys as type of int. So, this syntax is wrong ?
I have wrote that, **dictionary has n (n <= 15000) unique values**.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Ehsan Sajjad is correct. But I'd like to add another point:

You said that the strings in your `Dictionary` are unique. I don't know when you created the `Dictionary` and if the data is rather static or dynamically changing all the time.

If it's *rather static* and the *strings are unique*, you may consider to create a reversed `Dictionary` like this:

```
Dictionary<string, int> reversedDict = artikullar.ToDictionary(
    kvp => kvp.Value,
    kvp => kvp.Key);
```

and then use this for your lookup:

```
int key = reversedDict[txt_artikul.Text];
```

This may be faster than querying the original dictionary.

Answer (score 3):

You have to change :

```
val => val == txt_artikul.Text
```

to:

```
val = > val.Value == txt_artikul.Text
```

you have instance of `KeyValuePair`, you have to specify `Value` in lambda expression to be compared.

Comment: While this does solve the specific problem the OP asked about his design choice is a very poor one. He will not get any of the `O(1)` benefits of a dictionary doing this and his lookup could be very slow.

Comment: you may be right, but question is about the problem he is facing with lambda expression

Comment: Sometimes [when someone asks you if they should use a old shoe or glass bottle to pound in a tail you need to tell them to stop what they are doing and go buy a hammer](http://weblogs.asp.net/alex_papadimoulis/408925).

Comment: @ScottChamberlain how to improve this search query performance?

Comment: @MirjalalTalishinski use two dictionaries, one for lookups by `int`, one for lookups by `string`. Keep them in sync whenever you add or remove a value, whatver you do to one, do to the other.

Comment: See René Vogt's answer for a example.

Comment: @ScottChamberlain every key comes with specific value from db and *it's static during the current session*. So, using the two different `List<int>` (for keys) and `List<string>` (for values) is another appreciated way?

Comment: that is not suitable in your case i guess